# How to make 2 objects collide with each other instead of passing through each other in Spritekit

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, collision

I am using spritekit to create a simple running game. I have a stickman and the ground, and I want the stickman to collide with the ground when he falls to it. However, he simply passes through the ground and out of the frame. Any ideas?

```
    //
    //  GameplayScene.h
    //  CodeRun
    //
    //  Created by Sebastian Cain on 8/16/14.
    //  Copyright (c) 2014 ASX Software. All rights reserved.
    //

    #import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>

    @interface GameplayScene : SKScene

    typedef NS_OPTIONS(uint32_t , ASXCollisionCategory){
    ASXCollisionCategoryGround = 1 << 0,
    ASXCollisionCategoryStickman = 1 << 1
};

@end


//
//  Ground.m
//  CodeRun
//
//  Created by Sebastian Cain on 8/16/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 ASX Software. All rights reserved.
//

#import "Ground.h"
#import "GameplayScene.h"

@implementation Ground

+ (instancetype)ground:(CGPoint)position{

    Ground *groundNode = [Ground spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor redColor] size:CGSizeMake(960, 50)];
    groundNode.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    groundNode.position = position;

    groundNode.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:CGSizeMake(960, 50)];
    groundNode.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = YES;
    groundNode.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
    groundNode.physicsBody.mass = 1000;

    groundNode.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = ASXCollisionCategoryGround;
    groundNode.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = ASXCollisionCategoryStickman;
    return groundNode;
}

@end

#import "Stickman.h"
#import "GameplayScene.h"
@implementation Stickman

+ (instancetype)stickman: (CGPoint)position{

    Stickman *stickmanNode = [Stickman spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"stick - Frame 1"];
    stickmanNode.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0);
    stickmanNode.position = position;

    stickmanNode.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:25.0 center:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(stickmanNode.frame), CGRectGetMidY(stickmanNode.frame))];
    stickmanNode.physicsBody.mass = 50;
    stickmanNode.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = YES;
    stickmanNode.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = ASXCollisionCategoryStickman;
    stickmanNode.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = ASXCollisionCategoryGround;



    NSArray *textures = @[
                          [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"stick - Frame 1"],
                          [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"stick - Frame 2"],
                          [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"stick - Frame 3"],
                          [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"stick - Frame 4"],
                          [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"stick - Frame 5"],
                          [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"stick - Frame 6"],
                          [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"stick - Frame 7"],
                          [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"stick - Frame 8"],
                          [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"stick - Frame 9"],
                          [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"stick - Frame 10"]];


    SKAction *stickmanAnimation = [SKAction animateWithTextures:textures timePerFrame:0.05];
    SKAction *stickmanRepeat = [SKAction repeatActionForever:stickmanAnimation];
    [stickmanNode runAction:stickmanRepeat];

    return stickmanNode;
}

@end

//
//  GameplayScene.m
//  CodeRun
//
//  Created by Sebastian Cain on 8/16/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 ASX Software. All rights reserved.
//

#import "GameplayScene.h"
#import "Stickman.h"
#import "Ground.h"


@implementation GameplayScene

-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
        /* Setup your scene here */
        SKSpriteNode *backgroundNode = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor whiteColor] size:self.frame.size];
        backgroundNode.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
        [self addChild:backgroundNode];

        Stickman *stickmanInGameplay = [Stickman stickman:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))];
        [self addChild:stickmanInGameplay];
        Ground *groundinGameplay = [Ground ground:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
        [self addChild:groundinGameplay];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Comment: You need to learn about collisions and contacts. http://www.lynda.com/iOS-tutorials/Detecting-contacts-collisions/146015/166871-4.html

Answer (score -1):

Are you adding `Ground` node to `(0, 0)` position with `(960, 50)` size? In this case the player will be spawned inside that physics body!

To implement the ground, get rid of `Ground` node and put the following into `GameplayScene` init method:

```
self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:self.frame];
self.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = ASXCollisionCategoryGround;
```

That's it.

Comment: the player is spawned in the center of the screen, and should fall to the ground. Strangely , i later moved the ground up, and the collision DID occur ~200 pixels below where the ground was. maybe it's a bug of spritekit. Thanks for the advice.